# How to get the @htmlDropDownList selected value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `@htmlDropDownList` as

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyList", new SelectList(Model.List, "Id", "Movie"))
```

in a mvc3 view.

How can I capture the selected value of this drop down list using javascript and use it to change the contents of the view according to the selected item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the value is simple:

```
$('#MyList').val()
```

For the second part of the question I need more info.

**UPDATE**

How would we use the value?

```
//get the url for the movie description , define id  as 0, so it is easier to replace lateron.
var moviedescriptionUrl = '@Url.Action("details", "movies", new { id = 0})';

//get the movieid
var movieID = $('#MyList').val();

//update a div
$('#movie-description').load(moviedescriptionUrl.replace('0', movieID));
```

Assuming I have an "details" action that return a partial view.

Comment: Thanks.Say I have it as  var a = $('#MyList').val(); then how can I use that value and change the content of the exsiting view using an ajax call??I'm using MVC3 views